# iOS APP With ARC no leaking but live bytes increasing

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, memory-leaks

Thanks a lot to @Hot Licks's help, He points out what's wrong with my sqlite3's codes. I modify the codes and the live bytes increasing by sqlite3 are gone.

For other new ios developers may also face this problem, I leave the original questions in the latter part.

My new question is: there still are some increasing live bytes between every generation in instruments, but it seems that all the objects are made of ios SDK's codes, not my codes.
So should I leave the increasing alone, and don't need to worry about it?

[image]

@Hot Licks says there may be a problem in my way to manipulate the UI, so I describe it in detail:

1) I create a master detail app for ipad in Xcode 5;

2) Make the master embed in Tab bar controller, and add one new tab, so the master is a tab bar controller with 2 tabs. All these things are done in storyboard.

3) Delete the default label in the detail controller. Add a tableview, a textview and 3 buttons in the detail view. Add a prototype cell in the tableview. All these things are done in storyboard.

4) Connect the tableview, the textview as an outlet in detailViewController.h.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *explanationText;
```

5) modify the function: "tableview: didSelectRowAtIndexPath" in the master controller:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    LHBPoetry *poetry = [_searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    self.detailViewController.poetryId = poetry.poetryId;
}
```

6) modify the codes in detail view controller, please check it in the latter part, "a related snippet of the detail controller's code"

Is there a problem in it?

Thanks a lot for helping!!!

The older part :

When I debug my app, in simulator, the memory (live bytes) is continuously increasing, but there is no leaking in Instruments.

My questions are:

1. What is wrong with my code? I guess maybe every time I click an item, the detail's interface is recreated?
2. How can I find the leaking code?
3. Because of some enthusiasts' help, I narrow down my problem to the codes about fetching data from sqlite3. What is wrong with these code?
4. I create a default master-detail app, I click items in master for many times, and its live bytes also increase. So does this mean I don't need to worry about this problem?

My app is a master-detail app, using ARC, SDK is iOS 7, using Xcode 5 to write code.

What is this app doing:
In the left master navigation, there are many items, and in the right detail view there is a table. When users click on an item, the contents of the table in the detail view will change.

The problem is every time I click on an item in the master navigation, the memory will increase for about 150K~300K.

Code:

a related snippet of the master controller's code:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    LHBPoetry *poetry = poetryArray[indexPath.row];
    self.detailViewController.poetryId = poetry.poetryId;
}
```

a related snippet of the detail controller's code:

```
@interface LHBDetailViewController (){
    LHBPoetry *poetry;
    NSArray *sentenceArray;
    PoetryDao *poetryDao;
    PoetryService *poetryService;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIPopoverController *masterPopoverController;
- (void)configureView;


@end

@implementation LHBDetailViewController

#pragma mark - Managing the detail item

- (void)setPoetryId:(int)poetryId
{
    if (_poetryId != poetryId) {
        _poetryId = poetryId;

        // Update the view.
        [self configureView];
    }

    if (self.masterPopoverController != nil) {
        [self.masterPopoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    }
}

- (void)configureView
{
    // Update the user interface for the detail item.

    if (self.poetryId > 0) {
        poetry = [poetryDao getPoetryById:self.poetryId];
    }else{
        poetry = [poetryDao getPoetryById:1];
    }

    if(poetry != nil){
        //custom title
        if(poetry.dynasty != nil){
            self.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@  [%@]%@", poetry.name, poetry.dynasty, poetry.author];
        }else{
            self.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@  %@", poetry.name, poetry.author];
        }

        //refresh sentenceArray
        sentenceArray = [poetryService changeStringToArray:poetry.content withSplitter:[LHBConstant getPoetrySplitter]];

    }else{
        //custom title
        self.title = @"";
    }

    [_tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    poetryDao = [[PoetryDao alloc] init];
    poetryService = [[PoetryService alloc] init];

    [self configureView];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"detailCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...

    NSString *sentence = sentenceArray[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = sentence;

    return cell;
}


@end
```

I read an [this article about using Heapshot Analysis to find a leak](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17/when-is-a-leak-not-a-leak-using-heapshot-analysis-to-find-undesirable-memory-growth/#more-1949).

In Xcode, I use Product->Profile, to open instruments, then select Memory -> Allocations.
Then I do this:

1. In instruments, Click "Mark Generation";
2. In my app, click an item in the master view.
   repeat this 2 steps for several times.

I got [results from instruments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WruAG.png).

open an generation, [I got this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDlMy.png).

I compare all the generations, and I find that an object increases every time I click an item in master navigation.

[image]

It points to codes of sqlite3:

[image]

Here is the snippet of code:

```
-(LHBPoetry *) getPoetryById:(int) poetryId{
    sqlite3 *database;

    @try{
        //open database
        if(sqlite3_open([[LHBConstant dataFilePath] UTF8String], &database)!=SQLITE_OK){
            sqlite3_close(database);
            NSAssert(0, @"Failed to open database.");
        }

        //find in database
        NSString *query = @"SELECT id,name,author,dynasty, content, explanation, has_license, has_mastered FROM poetry where id = ?";
        sqlite3_stmt *statement;
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [query UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil)==SQLITE_OK){
            //bind parameter
            sqlite3_bind_int(statement, 1, poetryId);

            while (sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_ROW) {
                int primaryId = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);
                char *name = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1);
                char *author = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2);
                char *dynasty = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3);
                char *content = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 4);
                char *explanation = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 5);
                int hasLicense = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 6);
                int hasMastered = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 7);

                NSString *nameNS = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:name];
                NSString *authorNS = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:author];
                NSString *dynastyNS = dynasty == nil ? NULL : [NSString stringWithUTF8String:dynasty];
                NSString *contentNS = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:content];
                NSString *explanationNS = explanation == nil ? NULL : [NSString stringWithUTF8String:explanation];

                LHBPoetry *poetry = [[LHBPoetry alloc] initWithId:primaryId withName:nameNS withAuthor:authorNS withDynasty:dynastyNS withContent:contentNS withExplanation:explanationNS withLicense:hasLicense withMastered:hasMastered];

                return poetry;
            }
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        }else{
            NSLog(@"poetry getPoetryById fail. database is not ready.");
        }
    }
    @catch (NSException *e) {
        NSLog(@"%@", e);
    }
    @finally {
        sqlite3_close(database);
    }

    return nil;
}
```

and the method `dataFilePath` in `LHBConstant` is:

```
+(NSString *)dataFilePath{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    documentDirectory = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingString: @"/p140107"];
    return documentDirectory;
}
```

I also use "memory->leak" template in instruments, there's no leak.

Anyone could help me out?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please note that `IOS` isn't the same as `iOS`. `IOS` stands for http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cisco_IOS whilst `iOS` stands for http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS

Comment: If you study the instrument results carefully you will most likely see that some particular class of object is accumulating more and more instances.  What kind of object that is will probably lead you to your problem.

Comment: @HotLicks Thanks a lot! I have tried to look into the results in instruments, as I mentioned in this question, I followed a tutorial about finding leak with instruments. But I'm a new ios developer, and I don't have any clue about this...

Comment: @abentotoro try to comment any complex code and run your project and see whether if you still getting same problem

Comment: because i had same memory issue day before yesterday i made simple mistake in my coding its leads to 1gb live bytes

Comment: @Yohan Thanks a lot! I narrow down the problem to the codes about operating sqlite3, I update my post. But I don't know what's wrong with these codes.

Answer (score 1):

`return poetry;` -- I'm not convinced that returning like that will cause the `@finally` clause to execute.  And certainly the `sqlite3_finalize(statement);` statement does not get executed.

Comment: Thank you very much!! Yes, The finally clause was executed, but              sqlite3_finalize(statement) was not executed. I change the return clause. And the sqlite3's increasing live bytes is gone. Before this modification, the live bytes increase 180K between every generation, and after this modification, the live bytes increase only 90K. I check this 90K's objects, it seems they are all ios SDK's code, not my code. So does it mean I can leave the increasing live bytes alone, don't need to worry about it?

Comment: @abentotoro - I suspect you've still got a leak.  There are very few storage leak bugs in iOS, since they're relatively easy to spot in testing.  The way you describe it (though rather vague) makes me suspect that there's a bug in the way you manipulate the UI interface.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I update my way to manipulate the UI interface in the post, Could you please see if anything is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

What I have realized so far, IF there is a private instance variable on view controller and you pop it, the view controller is not being deallocated. In other words, `dealloc` method of the view controller is not being called once you have a private instance variable. For instance you have a UIView *_v , and NSTimer *_t as a private instance variable like below:

```
@implementation MyViewController{

    UIView *_v;
    NSTimer *_t;
}
```

What I'm doing is to make them nil just before popping the view controller from view hierarchy. I think ARC will still be able to deallocate MyViewController sometime after it needs memory.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I try to remove all my private instance from detailContoller.m, and put them into detailController.h as a property, this does make things right.

Answer (score 0):

You have some questions that are going to be tough to answer.

> Because of some enthusiasts' help, I narrow down my problem to the codes about fetching data from sqlite3. What is wrong with these code?

For Sqlite and debug builds:

1. ensure `NDEBUG` is not defined
2. ensure `DEBUG` is defined
3. use `SQLITE_DEBUG` preprocessor
4. use `SQLITE_MEMDEBUG` preprocessor

Otherwise, SQLite goes into 'release' mode automatically (from `sqlite3.c`, line 14816):

```
#if !defined(NDEBUG) && !defined(SQLITE_DEBUG)
# define NDEBUG 1
#endif
```

Also, from `sqlite3.c`, line 7780:

```
/*
** Exactly one of the following macros must be defined in order to
** specify which memory allocation subsystem to use.
**
**     SQLITE_SYSTEM_MALLOC          // Use normal system malloc()
**     SQLITE_WIN32_MALLOC           // Use Win32 native heap API
**     SQLITE_ZERO_MALLOC            // Use a stub allocator that always fails
**     SQLITE_MEMDEBUG               // Debugging version of system malloc()
**
** On Windows, if the SQLITE_WIN32_MALLOC_VALIDATE macro is defined and the
** assert() macro is enabled, each call into the Win32 native heap subsystem
** will cause HeapValidate to be called.  If heap validation should fail, an
** assertion will be triggered.
**
** If none of the above are defined, then set SQLITE_SYSTEM_MALLOC as
** the default.
```

You can also use `SQLITE_CONFIG_MALLOC` to `sqlite3_config` to use Xcode's memory manager if needed. Take a look at `sqlite3_mem_methods`. It may help with tracking.
Also, be sure you are calling `sqlite3_free` on error message strings from SQLite.

Finally, you can query SQlite for its memory statistics (from `sqlite3.c`, line 1550):

```
** [[SQLITE_CONFIG_MEMSTATUS]] <dt>SQLITE_CONFIG_MEMSTATUS</dt>
** <dd> ^This option takes single argument of type int, interpreted as a
** boolean, which enables or disables the collection of memory allocation
** statistics. ^(When memory allocation statistics are disabled, the
** following SQLite interfaces become non-operational:
**   <ul>
**   <li> [sqlite3_memory_used()]
**   <li> [sqlite3_memory_highwater()]
**   <li> [sqlite3_soft_heap_limit64()]
**   <li> [sqlite3_status()]
**   </ul>)^
** ^Memory allocation statistics are enabled by default unless SQLite is
** compiled with [SQLITE_DEFAULT_MEMSTATUS]=0 in which case memory
** allocation statistics are disabled by default.
** </dd>
```